# FuelPHP- Using Asset::img() with images fetched from database by for loop

Tags: php, image, fuelphp

```
<?php foreach($works as $work) : ?> 
<?php echo Asset::img('project-icons/icon/$work->cover_img', array('class'=>'img-responsive', 'alt'=>'...')); ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am using FuelPHP to build a portfolio website. PHP v5.6
This is the "works" section where images and details of a "work" are fetched from database. Using foreach loop. I want to get the "cover_img" (which is the image name), inside the `Asset::img(..)`

How to do this? what to put in place of `$work->cover_img`?

Edit: I was able to get the result by using this:

```
<img src="<?php echo Uri::base(false); ?>/assets/img/project-icons/icon/<?php echo $work->cover_url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="..." />
```

Can this be achieved by using Asset::img() instead of Uri::base()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
<?php 
echo Asset::img('project-icons/icon/'.$work->cover_img, array('class'=>'img-responsive', 'alt'=>'...')); 
?>
```

...?

Comment: Ah! The obvious. Thanks, I was doing this 
<?php 
echo Asset::img('project-icons/icon/'.$work->cover_img .'', array('class'=>'img-responsive', 'alt'=>'...')); 
?>